# Change URL by filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, controller, routes, nested-routes

I am using friendly_id so that I can create such URLs:

```
/search/france/weekly/toyota-95
```

My routes:

```ruby
scope to: 'search#show' do
  get '/search/:car_country_id/:rental_type_id/:car_group_id', as: 'search_country'
end
```

At the `search#show` view I have a form:

```ruby
<%= form_tag search_country_path, :method => :get do %>
    <%= select_tag(:car_country_id, options_from_collection_for_select(CarCountry.all, :slug, proc {|c| c.name }, {:selected => @country}), class: "Select-control u-sizeFull") %>
    <%= submit_tag t('shared.search'), class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

And search controller:

```ruby
@country = CarCountry.friendly.find(params[:car_country_id])
```

So ok, my intention is to change the URL as:

```
/search/italy/weekly/toyota-95
```

But the thing is, Rails params always sending **france** as `car_country_id` when I select country from select tag and submit it.

So what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, two `car_country_id` are sent to Rails server. You can rename one of them:

```ruby
<%= select_tag(:new_car_country_id, options_from_collection_for_select(CarCountry.all, :slug, proc {|c| c.name }, {:selected => @country}), class: "Select-control u-sizeFull") %>
```

In your controller, you should check whether `new_car_country_id` exists. If it does, then redirect to the corresponding path.

Another way is to make sure that the two `car_country_id` are the same. You should change the form's submit path once `select_tag` is updated with JavaScript.